# Getting error while running spring boot application from command line using java -jar \target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: spring-boot

I have packaged a spring boot service using Maven "mvn    package" and 
I am successfully able to create the jar. But when I run it from command line using below command : 
    "java -jar \target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" 
I am getting below error ::

```
java.io.IOException:    Unable to open nested jar file 'lib/JavaPNS-jar-2.2.0.jar'
Caused by: java.io.IOException:    Unable to find ZIP central directory records after reading 65792 bytes
```

Above jar "JavaPNS-jar-2.2.0.jar" i am referening in my pom.xml from my local file system using below : 
    
            JavaPNS
            JavaPNS-jar
            2.2.0
    
    
            in-project
            In Project Repo
            file://${project.basedir}/lib

When i run the application using "mvn spring-boot:run" command it runs fine without any error.

I have tried below options to resolve this :

1. Cleared the local cache of Maven and then again build the application. But it does not help to resolve it.
2. Also I tried to add the jar again to make sure that it is not corrupt.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: try to unzip demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar then again unzip JavaPNS-jar-2.2.0.jar (from the 1st step result) and see if you can unzip it.

Comment: Tried the same but doesn't help.

Comment: When i run the application using "mvn spring-booot:run" command, it comes up fine but give below warning : [WARNING] The POM for JavaPNS:JavaPNS-jar:jar:2.2.0 is missing, no dependency information available. Can it be the reason for the above issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using a workaround. I created a lib folder inside my spring boot project folder structure and copied the JavaPNS-jar-2.2.0.jar inside lib folder and then referenced the jar using Add jars option inside configure build path in Eclipse.

Then I again packaged it using Maven. And now created jar is working fine without any issues!!